# Flutter java.io.FileNotFoundException: Error

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, sign

Hey guys i tried to sign my app but this error always pops up.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Benutzer\Administrator\upload-keystore.jks
```

This is the error. It says that it can't find the path, what makes sense because this doesn't exist because I wanna create that. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you created file then use this.
c:/Benutzer/Administrator/upload-keystore.jks
if you not created file then just create file for sign for verification pass keys.